# Determine triangle type WITHOUT logical operators JAVA

Tags: java, operator-keyword

I'm supposed to write two programs to determine the type of triangle, given side lengths. One program can use logical operators. One can not. Here's my solution to the first program:

```
if (S1 == S2 AND S2 == S3)
    System.out.println("equalateral");
else if (S1 == S2 OR S2 == S3 OR S1 == S3)
    System.out.println("isoceles");
else
    System.out.println("scalene");
```

I think that part is correct, but I'm totally drawing a blank as to how I would NOT use logical operators. I thought maybe something with boolean, but that just goes back to me using logical operators. The exact directions are,

"Write the code using nested if-else statements, where every if has a matching else block and all if conditions are simple conditions, with no logical operators in them."

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your code won't compile. There is no such thing `AND` and `OR` in Java.

Comment: The "exact directions" are pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: Well, for *and* you just need nested if statements. For *or*, you need else statements... it's hard to hint much more than that without just doing the work for you. It's a pretty crazy exercise though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there is no `AND` or `OR` in Java.  Try `&&` and `||`.

But alternative to the `logical operators`, you can use the `comparison operators`.

```
if(S1 == S2) {
    if(S2 == S3) {
        //equilateral
    } else {
        //isosceles
    }
} else if(S2 == S3) {
    //isosceles
} else {
    //scalene
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing this on paper first. I hate writing those && symbols. So == isn't considered a logical operator? Is that because it doesn't modify anything?

Comment: @user2887591 no, == isn't a logical operator.  Not because it doesn't modify anything: neither do && or || (no matter how they're spelled).

Comment: `&&` and `||` are `logical operators` because they work on `logical values`.  They take two `boolean` arguments and return a `boolean`.  Consider: `(27 && 42)` will return `true` but `(27 == 42)` will return `false`.